# Edit sql row before adding it to an array in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a php script that gets data from a sql database then adds it to an array and encodes it in json then prints it, but I want to edit one of the items before it gets added to the array, how would I go about editing `$row['name']` before it got added to the array?

Sorry if this was really confusing!

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database", $con);

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT name,email,phone FROM table;");       
        $rows = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {           
            $rows[] = $row;
         }
        $jTableResult = array();
        $jTableResult['aaData'] = $rows;
        print json_encode($jTableResult);
```

Comment: Like, `while(...){$row["name"]="name";$rows[]=$row;}` this?

Comment: @Passerby I just want to edit "name" before it gets added to the array.

Comment: inside the while, $row['name'] = function($row['name'])?

Comment: @WilliamL. Yes, isn't that what my code does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    $row['name'] = YourFunction($row['name']); //change it however you want
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if($row['name'])
{
// do here what you want.
}  
$rows[] = $row;
}
```

May be it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to modify `$row['name']`, you might find MySQL's [String functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) useful.

I am assuming that you want to do this modification within the query.

```
// Add a string to the end of name
$result = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(name, 'string') name, email, phone FROM table");

// Or try replacing a part of the string
$result = mysql_query("SELECT REPLACE(name, 'old', 'new') name, email, phone FROM table");

$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {           
  $rows[] = $row;
}
```

- [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) documentation
- [REPLACE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) documentation